# Почему мои медиа запросы не перекрывают основные стили?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

В тег head я сначала подключил bootstrap 4, а после свои стили. Пишу на SASS.
Все работало нормально, но когда я написал медиа запрос, то стили в нем не перекрывают основные стили. А если добавить !important, тогда все работает.
Почему так? Я не хочу все время писать !important =(

Comment: Я сталкивался с такой проблемой. В моем случае файл с медиазапросами был определен раньше чем основной файл со стилями. Возможно у вас так же. Поэтому медиазапросы должны быть после основных стилей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно у вас проблемы с вложеностью селекторов.
Допустим если ранее вы обратились к блоку подобным образом:
.parent .parent_item .parent_item_tit { display: block;}
То попытка переопределить стили таким образом не сработает:
.parent_item_tit {display: inline-block;}

Comment: Точно) большое спасибо

Comment: @Александр Филимоненко если ответ Вам помог отметьте его галочкой ...